# How to aggregate?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have result of a join of two temporary tables in a CTE- the join has following fields: `ID, year, flag1, flag2`
I will call it Table1

```
ID   year flag1 flag2
1    2000  1     0
2    2001  0     1
3    2005  1     0
4    NULL  NULL  NULL
5    NULL  NULL  NULL
```

In  Table2 I have following data

```
4    2006  0     1
5    2007  0     1
```

How do i aggregate both the tables? and display records with ID's 1,2,3 from result of my join and ID's 4,5 from Table2?

How can i aggregate the data between both tables? and display result as below?

```
ID   year flag1 flag2
1    2000  1     0
2    2001  0     1
3    2005  1     0
4    2006  0     1
5    2007  0     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join on ID and use coalesce() or isnull() to get the correct (non null) values for ID 4 & 5:

```
SELECT 
  t1.ID, 
  coalesce(t1.[year], t2.[year]) as [year], 
  coalesce(t1.flag1, t2.flag1) as flag1, 
  coalesce(t1.flag2, t2.flag2) as flag2 
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

coalesce() (and isnull()) will return the first non null value of its arguments.

This might give incorrect results if the Table1 and Table2 has matching IDs that have non null values for the other fields though... but for your example it would work.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. What do I do in case my fields have NON-NULL columns though?

Comment: @sweety Then the current query it would take the values from Table1 and disregard values from Table2. This might not be what you want, so you might want to filter out rows from Table2 so that it just gets the rows with null values. You could do that in a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id int,years int,flag int,flag1 int)
insert into @t (Id,years,flag,flag1)values (1,2000,1,0),
(2,2001,0,1),(3,2005,1,0),(NULL,NULL,NULL,null),(NULL,NULL,NULL,null)

declare @tT table (Id int,years int,flag int,flag1 int)
insert into @tT (Id,years,flag,flag1)values (4,2006,0,1),
(5,2007,0,1)

SELECT T.Id,T.years,T.flag,T.flag1 FROM @t T 
WHERE  T.Id is not null and T.years is not null and T.flag is not null and T.flag1 is not null 
union 
SELECT T.Id,T.years,T.flag,T.flag1 FROM @tT T
WHERE  T.Id is not null and T.years is not null and T.flag is not null and T.flag1 is not null
```